# Trying to downgrade the Steam version of Stardew Valley on Linux from 1.3 to 1.2

Tags: steam, linux, stardew-valley

I'm trying to downgrade my Steam version of Stardew Valley from 1.3 to 1.2 on Linux (for the .xnb mods), and I stumbled upon this [tutorial](https://www.speedrun.com/stardew_valley/thread/wfuzk/1#b4a8z), which explains how to downgrade, but has the Windows version AppID, DepotID, and ManifestID. Does anyone know the AppID, DepotID, and ManifestID for the 1.2 Linux version?

Comment: Please note that I own this game, and therefore this is completely legal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure:

- AppID: 413150 (same for all platforms)
- DepotID: 413153
- ManifestID: 6405006757821704906

Do note that the AppID is the same for all platforms. Also, the ManifestID is for the GNU/Linux build released at the same date as the Windows 1.2 build - listed in the tutorial you linked - was released.

#### How do I find this information myself?

1. Find the AppID by going to the steam store page for the desired game, the AppID will be the number after `/app/` in the URL.
2. Go to https://steamdb.info/app/appid, replace `appid` with the AppID you found previously.
3. There should be a 'depot' tab, either to the left or on the top of the page (depending on screen size), click that to find the depot for your platform. The depots are listed with their DepotIDs in order and with names. Click on the one that is the main depot for your platform (in this case, it was named {game} Linux).
4. You should now be on a https://steamdb.info/depot/id page, click the 'Manifests' tab. This tab lists all possible builds you can downgrade to.

And just in case the tutorial disappears, here's how to apply it:

#### How to downgrade:

1. Open this in your browser: `steam://nav/console` to open the Steam Client console.
2. Type the following command (replace the `<id>s` with your chosen ids):

```
download_depot <appid> <depotid> <manifestid>
```

3. Wait for the download to finish, there won't be any progressbar. You can check your downloads page to see if it's downloading, but restarting the client will end the download.
4. When the download is done Steam will show you where the files were downloaded to.
5. Go to the games installation directory and move the files somewhere else, then move the downloaded files into the game folder.
6. Done! Launching the game should now launch the downgraded version.

Comment: Note that this method was broken in February 2020 by a Steam client update.

There is a third party tool available to do this now; the following YouTube video goes into good detail about how it works: https://youtu.be/44HBxzC_RTg